# SQL aggregation group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an employee table and a leave_allocation table which has a one-to-many relationship, Each employee has a number of leave allocations over a period of time. I would like to get the LATEST allocation for each employee.

I tried the query but the date and the days values do not correlate to the same row

```
select e.employee_number, e.nme, MAX(l.date), l.days 
from employee e, leave_allocation l 
where l.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by e.employee_number, e.nme
```

How can I get the latest allocation per employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `MAX()` date in a subquery:

```
SELECT e.employee_number, e.nme, l.leavedate, la.days
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT Max(date) leavedate, employee_id
   FROM leave_allocation
   GROUP BY employee_id
) l
   ON e.employee_id = l.employee_id
INNER JOIN leave_allocation la
   ON l.employee_id = la.employee_id
   AND l.leavedate = la.date
```

I also switched the query to use ANSI join syntax instead of commas between the tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.employee_number
      ,e.nme
      ,l.days
  FROM employee e
      , leave_allocation l
      ,(SELECT employee_id
              ,MAX(DATE) date
          FROM leave_allocation
         GROUP BY employee_id) m
 WHERE l.employee_id = e.employee_id
   AND l.employee_id = m.employee_id
   AND l.date = m.date
```

If there can be multiple rows with same employee_number and date, then you need to sum.

```
SELECT e.employee_number
      ,e.nme
      ,sum(l.days)
  FROM employee e
      , leave_allocation l
      ,(SELECT employee_id
              ,MAX(DATE) date
          FROM leave_allocation
         GROUP BY employee_id) m
 WHERE l.employee_id = e.employee_id
   AND l.employee_id = m.employee_id
   AND l.date = m.date
GROUP BY e.employee_number
        ,e.nme
```

Comment: note that this will produce duplicates if the combination of employee id and date are not unique in leave_allocation.

Comment: @ Eric Petroelje - Yes, but my assumption is they were, otherwise, what would be the point of having 2 rows with same employee id and date? Anyway, I proposed an alternative just in case there can be multiple rows, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  e.employee_number, e.nme, c.maxDate, l.days 
FROM    employee e 
            INNER JOIN leave_allocation l
                ON l.employee_id = e.employee_id
            INNER JOIN
            (
                select employee_id, MAX(date) maxDate
                from    leave_allocation  
                group by employee_id
            ) c ON c.employee_id = l.employee_ID AND
                    c.maxDate = l.date
```